# storing the selected value from drop down list to a variable in php

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have populated a drop down list using values from a database in my web page. I use **MySQL** database and **PHP** for coding and **HTML** for design. Now, if I select a value from the drop down list and submit it, I want the selected value to be stored in a new variable. I will transfer the variable again to a new web page. 
I tried to do this using the **$_GET** and **$_REQUEST** codes, but none of them work. Please suggest me the solutions.

Here is the code:

PHP and HTML code for Drop Down List:

```
<?php
$yearval=$_GET['year'];
$classval=$_GET['class'];
$semesterval=$_GET['semester'];
mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); // (host, username, password)
mysql_select_db("digint") or die("Unable to select database"); //select db
?>
<table width="500" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td>SELECT YOUR SUBJECT AND ENTER THE SUBJECT ACCESS CODE</td>
<table width="400" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<form method="post" action="accesscheck.php">
<tr>
<td>Select Subject</td>
<td>
<?php
//Subject selection
$result = mysql_query("select DISTINCT subject from accessindex where semester=$semesterval");
echo '<select id="subject" name="subject"><OPTION>';
echo "Select a subject</OPTION>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$subject = $row["subject"];
echo "<OPTION value=\"$subject\">$subject</OPTION>";
}
echo '</SELECT>';
?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">AccessKey</td>
<td width="294"><input name="myaccesskey" type="password" id="myaccesskey"></td>
</tr>
<td>
<input type="submit" name="AccessCheck" value="Submit">
</td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP code for using the selected value:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$myaccesskey=$_POST['myaccesskey']; 
$subjectval=$_POST['subject'];

$myaccesskey = stripslashes($myaccesskey);
$myaccesskey = mysql_real_escape_string($myaccesskey);
$subjectval = stripslashes($subjectval);
$subjectval = mysql_real_escape_string($subjectval);
$sql="SELECT accesskey FROM accessindex WHERE accesskey='$myaccesskey' and subject=$subjectval";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1){
header("location:marksentry.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Subject Access Key";
}
```

Comment: Where is your tried code?

Comment: show us code. which you have tried

Answer (score 1):

After submit you can get value of select drop down using method you used `GET` or `POST`

`$select_val = $_POST['subject'];`

Where `$_POST['subject']` is selected value of dropdown and `subject` is a name of dropdown

**Try this**

```
<?php
//Subject selection
$result = mysql_query("select DISTINCT subject from accessindex where semester=$semesterval");
echo '<form method="POST" action="new_webpage_action.php">';
echo '<select id="subject" name="subject"><OPTION>';
echo "Select a subject</OPTION>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$subject = $row["subject"];
echo "<OPTION value=\"$subject\">$subject</OPTION>";
}
echo '</SELECT>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

Comment: Which method you used in form ? like method= ?

Comment: i used post method in form

Comment: what is your dropdown name ? and can you share code with us ?

Comment: Where is your form and submit button ?